# \index inside footnote: How to propagate the footnote number correctly with index package?

Tags: footnotes, indexing

We're using the `index` package in order to get several indexes (name index, subject index, language index), and we're basically happy with it. There's only one obstinate problem: `index` does not propagate footnote numbers as desired, unlike `makeidx` (which doesn't support multiple indexes though):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\fn#1#2{%
\hyperpage{#2}n#1%
}%

\newcommand{\is}[1]{\if@noftnote%
\index{#1}%
\else%
\index{#1|fn{\thefootnote}}%
\fi%
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\footnote{First footnote.}
\footnote{Second footnote.\is{inside second footnote}}
\footnote{Third footnote.}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

This outputs `inside second footnote, 1n3` instead of `inside second footnote, 1n2`. Hence, `\thefootnote` seems to be expanded at the very end, and not immediately in the footnote.

Any suggestions how to do it right with `index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expand `\thefootnote`, or it will be essentially written in unusable form in the `.idx` file:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\fn[2]{\hyperpage{#2}n#1}

\makeatletter
\let\if@noftnote\iffalse % just for the example
\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
  \if@noftnote
    \index{#1}%
  \else
    \edef\tempnumber{\thefootnote}%
    \expandafter\footnoteindex\expandafter{\tempnumber}{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\footnoteindex}[2]{\index{#2|fn{#1}}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\footnote{First footnote.}
\footnote{Second footnote.\is{inside second footnote}}
\footnote{Third footnote.}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I guess `\if@noftnote` is set by some other part of your full code, so I just let it to `\iffalse`.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure I must have missed something, but the index entry I'm getting is: "inside second footnote, 1n3". I tried it both in PDFTeX and DVI TeX. Same output. I'm using MacTeX '15.

Comment: @sgmoye As it often happens, I pasted the wrong code, sorry. I'll fix in a moment.

Answer (score 4):

The `imakeidx` package provides multiple index files as well and does expand the footnote number correctly.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\fn#1#2{%
\hyperpage{#2}n#1%
}%

\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
\if@noftnote%
\index{#1}%
\else%
\index{#1|fn{\number\value{footnote}}}%
\fi%
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\footnote{First footnote.}
\footnote{Second footnote.\is{inside second footnote}}
\footnote{Third footnote.}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Switching to `imakeidx` is on my agenda. But for now, I want `index` to do the job.