# imakeidx - A special feature for footnotes

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

The question is similar to those about [indexing footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282591/index-inside-footnote-how-to-propagate-the-footnote-number-correctly-with-inde). The answers I could read provide commands that produce an output like the following when the word to be indexed occurs on the same page both in text and in footnotes (see MWE):

```
Index entry, 1n1, 1n2, 1,...
```

What I would like is that the indexing command took into account the previous occurence of the word  to produce something like this:

```
Index entry, 1 and n, 25, 42n, 51 and n,...
```

where there is no reference to the footnote number (so no need to hyperref to the note) and the `and` should of course be language sensitive (e.g. an `e` for Italian users).

*Bonus (convoluted).* It could be nice to make it so that footnotes numbers may be indexed if wanted, but I can see many possible issues following such a request (`n` should turn to `nn` or `notes` if more than a footnote is indexed, and how about separating the numbers without getting messy?).
You can definitely ignore this one!

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Indice dei nomi,columns=2,intoc=true]
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\def\fn#1#2{%
\hyperpage{#2}~n%~#1%
}%

\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
\if@noftnote%
\index{#1}%
\else%
\index{#1|fn{\number\value{footnote}}}%
\fi%
}
\begin{document}
A statement about Some One\index{One, Some}.\footnote{For a different on S. One\is{One, Some} 
see\dots} Some text backed by a footnote.\footnote{As Another Scholar\is{Scholar, Another} once said}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The code for the `\is` indexer is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282609/212292