# \index inside \pagenote. How to propagate the pagenote number correctly?

Tags: indexing, pagenote

The following MWE is taken from [\index inside footnote: How to propagate the footnote number correctly with index package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282591/index-inside-footnote-how-to-propagate-the-footnote-number-correctly-with-inde/282610#282610) and used with the `pagenote` package. The index result shows: `inside second pagenote, 2n0` instead of `inside second pagenote, 2n2`. What needs to be done to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[page]{pagenote}

\newcommand\pn[2]{\hyperpage{#2}n#1}

\makeatletter
\let\if@nopnote\iffalse % just for the example
\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
    \if@nopnote
    \index{#1}%
    \else
    \edef\tempnumber{\thepagenote}%
    \expandafter\pagenoteindex\expandafter{\tempnumber}{#1}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\pagenoteindex}[2]{\index{#2|pn{#1}}}

\makeindex
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
    
First\index{First index} sentence.\pagenote{First pagenote.}
    
Second sentence with index inside pagenote.\pagenote{Second pagenote with index.\is{inside second pagenote}}
    
Third sentence.\pagenote{Third pagenote.}
    
\printnotes
    
\printindex
    
\end{document}
```

EDIT 1 - MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[page]{pagenote}

\newcommand\pn[2]{\hyperpage{#2}n#1}

\makeatletter
\let\if@nopnote\iffalse % just for the example
\newcommand{\is}[1]{%
    \if@nopnote
    \index{#1}%
    \else
    \expandafter\pagenoteindex\expandafter{\tempnumber}{#1}%
    \fi
}
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{%
    \edef\tempnumber{#1}%
    {\normalfont #1.} }
\makeatother
\newcommand{\pagenoteindex}[2]{\index{#2|pn{#1}}}

\makeindex[program=xindy]
\makepagenote

\begin{document}

First\index{First index} sentence.\pagenote{First pagenote.}
\clearpage

Second sentence\index{sentence@\emph{sentence}} with index inside pagenote.\pagenote{Second pagenote with index.\is{inside second pagenote}}

\clearpage
Third sentence.\pagenote{Third pagenote.\is{sentence@\emph{sentence}}}

\printnotes

\printindex

\end{document}
```

The index entry for "sentence" lacks the pagenumber when using `\makeindex[program=xindy]`, which is incorrect.
But with `\makeindex` only, there are double entries of "sentence" in the index list, which is incorrect too.
How can this be fixed?

EDIT 2 - Multiple Index with pagenote?!

Is there anyone knowing how to do this task also for multiple indexing like

```
\makeindex[name=things,title=Things,program=xindy]
\makeindex[name=names,title=Names,program=xindy]
```

I think the package `pagenote` needs here progression and development.
A MWE could be:

`````
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[page]{pagenote}

\newcommand\pn[2]{\hyperpage{#2}n#1}
\newcommand{\pagenoteindex}[3]{\index[#1]{#3|pn{#2}}}
\makeatletter
\let\if@nopnote\iffalse
\newcommand{\is}[2]{%
    \if@nopnote
    \index[#1]{#2}%
    \else
    \expandafter\pagenoteindex\expandafter{\tempnumber}{#2}%
    \fi
}
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{%
    \edef\tempnumber{#1}%
    {\normalfont #1.} }
\makeatother

\makeindex[program=xindy,title=Things,name=Things]
\makeindex[program=xindy,title=Names,name=Names]
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
    
WordOne\pagenote{WordOnePagenote-\is[Things]{WordOnePagenoteThings}}

WordTwoThings\index[Things]{WordTwoThings}

WordThree\pagenote{WordThreePagenote-\is[Names]{WordThreePagenoteNames}}

WordFourNames\index[Names]{WordFourNamenregister}

\printnotes

\printindex[Things]
\printindex[Names]

\end{document}
````
Thank you for attention and solutions.
`````

Comment: `\thepagenote` returns `0` inside the `\pagenote{}` so that's the value you get when you write it, expanded, to the `.idx`.

Comment: Can this behaviour be adjusted? To get the intended result?

Comment: I'm not sure. I mean: in some sense, yes. TeX is Turing complete and all that. But in practical terms? I'm not really familiar with this package and I'm not even sure what code is responsible for this, never mind why it is configured that way. You could try asking in chat. There are plenty of people who could read the code, but I only understand a fraction of a fraction of it.

Comment: You're not passing `\pn` 2 arguments? Does it pick up the other automatically?

Comment: Good question. Without the `\emph{}` indexing within `\pagenote{}` works correctly. And earlier `\makeindex[program=xindy]` solved this problem. I have no idea how a second argument can be placed.