# Pagenotes with multiple index and useage with tex4ebook - needs support

Tags: indexing, tex4ebook, pagenote

Please refer to [\index in \pagenote with splitindex option (for multiple index)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705565/index-in-pagenote-with-splitindex-option-for-multiple-index/705581?noredirect=1#comment1754478_705581)

With the following MWE no epub could be made with tex4ebook.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage[texindy,splitindex]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[hyperindex,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[page]{pagenote}

\input{pagenote-index-usageB.tex}% See code below
\makeindex[program=texindy,name=Names,title=Names]
\makeindex[program=texindy,name=Something,title=Something]
\makepagenote

\begin{document}
    
    First index.\index[Something]{First index} 
    
    Sentence.\pagenote{First pagenote without index.}
    
    \clearpage
    
    Emph index.\index[Something]{Emph index@\emph{Emph index}} 
    
    pagenote and index.\pagenote{Second pagenote with index.\protect\is[Something]{Index inside second pagenote|seealso{Emph index}}}
    
    \clearpage
    
    Third pagenote.\pagenote{\emph{Emph index word}.\protect\is[Something]{Emph index@\emph{Emph index}}\protect\is[Something]{Emph index@\emph{Emph index}|see{Index inside second pagenote}}}
    
    Namenindex\index[Names]{Namenindex}
    
    \printnotes
    
    \printindex[Something]
    \printindex[Names]
    
\end{document}
```

with help of the file `pagenote-index-usageB.tex`

```
\newcommand\pn[2]{\hyperpage{#2}\hyperlink{pn:#1}{A#1}}
\makeatletter
\let\if@nopnote\iffalse % just for the example
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{%
    \edef\tempnumber{#1}%
    \edef\temppgnumber{\thepage}%
    {\normalfont #1.} }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\is} { om }{%
    \if@nopnote
    \IfValueTF { #1 } {
        \index[#1]{#2}
    }{
        \index{#2}
    }
    \else
    \hypertarget{pn:\tempnumber}{}%
    \IfValueTF { #1 } {
        \thomkrates_pagenoteindex:nene { #1 } { \tempnumber } { #2 } { \temppgnumber }
    }{
        \thomkrates_pagenoteindex:ene { \tempnumber } { #2 } { \temppgnumber }
    }
    \fi
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomkrates_pagenoteindex:nnnn
{
    \index [#1] { #3 | pn {#2}{#4} }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thomkrates_pagenoteindex:nnnn { nene }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomkrates_pagenoteindex:nnn
{
    \index  { #2 | pn {#1}{#3} }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \thomkrates_pagenoteindex:nnn { ene }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```

pdflatex does a good job and the multiple index is working as intended with index entries pageAnotenum: xAn ... 324A84 for example.

But when producing an epub with tex4ebook the first `\index{}` gives an error..."extra }"

Is there a chance to get an epub with multiple index and pagenote-indexing?

Thank your for support.